# Why does collection+json use anonymous objects instead of key value pairs

Tags: schema, collection-json

I'm trying to find a data schema which can be used for different scenaries and a promissing format I found so far is the collection+json format (http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/ ).

So far it has a lot of the functionallity I need and is very flexible, however I don't get why it uses anonymous objects  ( example: `{"name" : "full-name", "value" : "J. Doe", "prompt" : "Full Name"},` ) instead of simple key value pairs. (example: "full-name": "J. Doe", ).

I see how you can transfer more information like the prompt, etc. but the parsing is much slower and it is harder to create a client for it since he has to access the fields by searching in an array. When binding the data to a spezific view, it has to be know which fields exists, so the anonymous objects have to be converted into a key value map again.

So is there a real advante using this anonymous objects instead of a key value map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this question and then forgott about it, but found the answer I looked for here:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/collectionjson/key/collectionjson/_xaXs2Q7N_0/GQkg2mvPjqMJ

From Mike Amundsen the creator of collection+JSON

> I understand your desire to add object serialization patterns to CJ.
>   However, one of the primary goals of my CJ design is to *not* support
>   object serialization. I know that serialization is an often-requested
>   feature for Web messages. It's a great way to optimize both the code
>   and the programmer experience. But it's just not what I am aiming for
>   in this particular design.
>
> I think the extension Kevin ref'd is a good option. Not sure if anyone
>   is really using it, tho. If you'd like to design one (based on your
>   "body" idea), that's cool. If you'd like to start w/ a gist instead of
>   doing the whole "pull" thing, that's cool. Post it and let's talk
>   about it.
>
> On another note, I've written a very basic client-side parser for CJ
>   (it's in the basic folder of the repo) to show how to hide the
>   "costly" parts of navigating CJ's state model cleanly.  I actually
>   have a work item to create a client-side lib that can convert the
>   state representation into an arbitrary local object model, but haven't
>   had time to do the work yet. Maybe this is something you'd like help
>   me with?
>
> At a deeper (and possibly more boring) level, this state-model
>   approach is part of a bigger pattern I have in mind to treat messages
>   as "type-less" containers and to allow clients and servers to utilize
>   whatever local object models they prefer - without the need for
>   cross-web agreement on that object model. This is an "opinionated
>   design model" that I am working toward.
>
> Finally, as you rightly point out at the top of the thread, HAL and
>   Siren are much better able to support object serialization style
>   messages. I think that's very cool and I encourage folks (including my
>   clients) to use these other formats when object serialization is the
>   preferred pattern and to use CJ when state transfer is the preferred
>   pattern.

Comment: Just for curiosity, you think that my answer was somehow wrong or not complete? I think that this part of mike's answer 'to treat messages as "type-less" containers and to allow clients and servers to utilize whatever local object models they prefer - without the need for cross-web agreement on that object model' which seems to me the same as saying 'the client does not need to have previous knowledge about your representation'.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it is wrong (gave you +1), I just thought it would be better to quote the answer from the creator of collection+json. Also the google groupe is a better place since he can anser questions there directly. Are you using collection+json?

Comment: Oh ok, it was just a clarification for me (and thanks for the +1 =). Yes I am using collection+json as the representation format for the new version of my back-end (from rest-like to full rest with hypermedia). Want to exchange notes?

Comment: Sure, do you have time on sunday?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the main reason is because a consumer client does not need to know in advance the format of the data.

As it is proposed now in collection+json, you know that in the data object you will find stuff about data simply by parsing through it, 'name' is always the identifying name for the field, 'value' is the value and so on, your client can be agnostic about how many fields or their names:

```
{
 "name" : "full-name", 
 "value" : "J. Doe", 
 "prompt" : "Full Name"
},
{
 "name" : "age", 
 "value" : "42", 
 "prompt" : "Age"
}
```

if you had instead

```
{
 "full-name" : "J. Doe", 
 "age" : "42"
}
```

the client needs to have previous knowledge about your representation, so it should expect and understand 'full-name', 'age, and all the application specific fields.